# Extending a Protocol that contains an array of Protocols in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols

I am trying to create a struct that extends a Protocol called `Pack`. The `Pack` protocol has the following fields:

```
protocol Pack {
    var title: String { get set }
    var cards: [Card] { get set }
}
```

Where `Card` is also a Protocol (with all string fields).

I have a struct titled `BaseballCard` that properly implements the `Card` protocol. However, when I try making a struct `BaseballPack` that looks like this:

```
 var id: String
    var title: String
    var description: String
    
    var cards: [BaseballCard]
```

Xcode flags this as an error and says that `BaseballPack` does not conform to the `Pack` protocol. It is only happy if I give it a property like `var cards: [Card]`.

However, `BaseballCard` correctly implements the `Card` Protocol. Any idea why this isn't allowed?

Comment: Look into `typealias` and `associatedType`